# Determining a cache hit/miss with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony2 project, I've configured my Doctrine 2 query to use the result cache:

```
public function findFoo($id)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('foo')
        ->where('foo.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->useResultCache(true)
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Is there any way to determine if my query resulted in a cache hit or miss? I can't find any mention of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used it, but [The Second Level Cache doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/second-level-cache.html#the-second-level-cache) mentions [Cache Log](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/second-level-cache.html#cache-log):

> By providing a cache logger you should be able to get information about all cache operations such as hits, misses and puts.

Answer (score 0):

This is too simple, as an app developer, this is exactly what the dev environment (app_dev.php) is used for. This environment comes with the profiler toolbar which displays exactly what database queries and query times where used to generate the response for that request (ajax too!). Simply reload the page and see whether the numbers differ no query yet with the same result means a successful cache hit. Don't complicate things, use the toolbar.